# How does Google Analytics site verification work?

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics

I am new to web development and I would like to verify site ownership using javascript, similar to what Google does with their analytics code. I have a django app that lets users sign up for a service, but I need to validate that they own the site. Here's a very high level description of what needs to happen:

1. The user signs up and is given a verification code
2. I generate a snippet of code to put on their site
3. They return to my site and click 'Verify'

Here's googles code. Can someone break down for me what this is doing and how it's used to verify site ownership?

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="verification code">
    (function(){

      // create a new script element
      var script   = document.createElement('script'),
      script.src   = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      script.async = true;

      // insert the script element into the document
      var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript)

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: The first block is to "create a new script element" that will load some more JS code. Then, the second block is to "insert the script element into the document". The "verification code" is simply a unique ID so that Google knows its you. Also: this has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was wondering if the inserted  script did anything with regards to verification. Also, this is a for a django app and I originally had inquiries in here regarding django but decided to leave it for another question. I forgot to delete the django tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ignore the js for the moment.  Your core question is how to verify site ownership. So I'm going to tackle that first.

What Google is doing is having you insert some code into a webpage that you have control of. The assumption is that if you have control of `www.example.com`, you can get that bit of code served at `www.example.com` to someone. And that's a pretty safe bet.

Now back to that code snippet you gave. For one thing, it didn't look familiar to me whatsoever. It must be an older format, because what's current is below:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-123456-7', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

In any any case, there's a great read here on why Google has changed their approach over time for how it loads this script: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/

Comment: Does the script do anything with regards to verification?  Or is site ownership verified just by the user putting the script on their page?

Comment: @JaniceLaset, yes, the script verifies that the account that wants to start tracking has ownership by putting the specific UA code there.

Comment: Thanks @raiderrobert! One last thing for clarification. Would putting the verification code in a meta tag do just as well? Or is there a benefit to putting it in a script? Are they just using the script for verification because it's used for tracking the page anyway and it's already there?

Comment: @JaniceLaset, not positive, but pretty sure, the script provides a pingback to the server. So it needs to be a script.